# MariaDB - Removing null attributes from a json result after a JSON_SEARCH

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am looking for a way to directly manipulate the search result as an array (JSON_SEARCH). More specifically to remove all null values in the json result. Unfortunately JSON_REMOVE expects either only one path string or N comma separated path strings. I can't use arrays, which are generated by JSON_SEARCH with the parameter "all".

I think it's a pity and it would be a useful function.

```
  SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[
  {
    "average": 2,
    "itemName": "Lorem ipsum...",
    "itemDescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...",
    "nullDescription": null,
    "option": {
      "quantization": null,
      "value": "Foo",
      "description": null
    }
  }
]', 'all', 'null') res
```

Generates:  `["$[0].nullDescription", "$[0].option.quantization", "$[0].option.description"]`

I cannot use this:

```
SELECT  JSON_REMOVE('[
  {
    "average": 2,
    "itemName": "Lorem ipsum...",
    "itemDescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...",
    "nullDescription": null,
    "option": {
      "quantization": null,
      "value": "Foo",
      "description": null
    }
  }
]', '["$[0].nullDescription", "$[0].option.quantization", "$[0].option.description"]') res
```

Only if I resolve the array via the api and start a new database query. Like for example:

```
SELECT  JSON_REMOVE('[
...see above...
]', "$[0].nullDescription", "$[0].option.quantization", "$[0].option.description") res
```

Try it:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=fd7978bc2269c80bb1c678d71aa205e4

**Solution thanks @Akina:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('[
...see above...
]', ',{0,}\s{0,}"[a-zA-Z]{0,}":.{0,}null|NULL,','')
```

**Update:**

In some cases this approach works. For example, when you have small json objects like in the example. However, I have a very large query in which no regex I found worked accurately.
First, see above for the revised RegEx.
Second, my solution was a new function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS JSON_REMOVE_NULL;
CREATE FUNCTION JSON_REMOVE_NULL (json_object_or_array JSON)
RETURNS JSON DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE indx INT DEFAULT 0;
  SET @array_of_res = JSON_SEARCH(json_object_or_array, 'all', 'null');
  WHILE indx < JSON_LENGTH(@array_of_res) DO
     SET @path = JSON_EXTRACT(@array_of_res, CONCAT("$[", indx, "]"));
     SET json_object_or_array = JSON_REMOVE(json_object_or_array, JSON_UNQUOTE(@path));
     SET indx = indx + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN json_object_or_array;
END;
```

Comment: You cannot operate array-over-array. Parse the result of searching to separate paths then remove them one-by-one in recursive CTE. Or use text-processing functions instead of JSON functions (REGEXP_REPLACE in MariaDB 10.5).

Comment: Thanks @Akina, that worked very well. My RagEX is: "[a-zA-Z]{0,}":.{0,}null.{0,}. I add it to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but worth mentioning that `JSON_MERGE_PATCH` might help you to clean JSON, at least JSON-object.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(
  JSON_MERGE_PATCH('{}', JSON_QUERY('[
    {
      "average": 2,
      "itemName": "Lorem ipsum...",
      "itemDescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...",
      "nullDescription": null,
      "option": {
        "quantization": null,
        "value": "Foo",
        "description": null
      }
    }
  ]', '$[0]'))
);
```

Result:

```
[{
  "average": 2,
  "itemName": "Lorem ipsum...",
  "itemDescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...",
  "option": {
    "value": "Foo"
  }
}]
```

How it works:

`JSON_MERGE_PATCH` ignores null-values, so by patching a empty object (`{}`)
you only get none null-values left.

A longer array demands some more work, but could be done:

```
SET @json = '[
  {
    "average": 1,
    "nullDescription": null,
    "option": {
      "value": "Foo1",
      "description": null
    }
  },
{
    "average": 2,
    "nullDescription": null,
    "option": {
      "value": "Foo2",
      "description": null
    }
  },
{
    "average": 3,
    "nullDescription": null,
    "option": {
      "value": "Foo3",
      "description": null
    }
  }
]';

SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_MERGE_PATCH('{}', JSON_QUERY(@json, CONCAT('$[',seq,']')))
    )
FROM seq_0_to_100000
WHERE seq < JSON_LENGTH(@json);

-- MariaDB < 10.5.0
SELECT CONCAT(
    '['
    , GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_MERGE_PATCH('{}', JSON_QUERY(@json, CONCAT('$[',seq,']')))
    ), ']')
FROM seq_0_to_100000
WHERE seq < JSON_LENGTH(@json);
```

This is using the MariaDB **Sequence Storage Engine** https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/